# How to get summary statistics by group

Tags: r, dplyr, stat, summarize, r-faq

I'm trying to get multiple summary statistics in R/S-PLUS grouped by categorical column in one shot. I found couple of functions, but all of them do one statistic per call, like `aggregate()`.

```
data <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 
          71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4,6,6,8)))
df <- data.frame(group=grp, dt=data)
mg <- aggregate(df$dt, by=df$group, FUN=mean)    
mg <- aggregate(df$dt, by=df$group, FUN=sum)
```

What I'm looking for is to get multiple statistics for the same group like mean, min, max, std, ...etc in one call, is that doable?

Comment: This one is a pretty basic question with multiple answers.  You may not be familiar with RSeek [(LINK)](http://www.rseek.org/) and the sos library [(LINK)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/index.html)  Both are great resources to help you figure out the answers to questions.  Ibet with those resources you'll be able to answer your own question in seconds.

Comment: There's an extra comma at the end of the `data <- c(` line.

Comment: I just found a wonderful R package [tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/). You can tabulate data by as many categories as you desire and calculate multiple statistics for multiple variables - it truly is amazing! But wait, there's more! The package has functions to generate LaTeX code for your tables for easy import to your documents.

Answer (score 146):

### **1. `tapply`**

I'll put in my two cents for `tapply()`.

```
tapply(df$dt, df$group, summary)
```

You could write a custom function with the specific statistics you want or format the results:

```
tapply(df$dt, df$group,
  function(x) format(summary(x), scientific = TRUE))
$A
       Min.     1st Qu.      Median        Mean     3rd Qu.        Max. 
"5.900e+01" "5.975e+01" "6.100e+01" "6.100e+01" "6.225e+01" "6.300e+01" 

$B
       Min.     1st Qu.      Median        Mean     3rd Qu.        Max. 
"6.300e+01" "6.425e+01" "6.550e+01" "6.600e+01" "6.675e+01" "7.100e+01" 

$C
       Min.     1st Qu.      Median        Mean     3rd Qu.        Max. 
"6.600e+01" "6.725e+01" "6.800e+01" "6.800e+01" "6.800e+01" "7.100e+01" 

$D
       Min.     1st Qu.      Median        Mean     3rd Qu.        Max. 
"5.600e+01" "5.975e+01" "6.150e+01" "6.100e+01" "6.300e+01" "6.400e+01"
```

### **2. `data.table`**

The `data.table` package offers a lot of helpful and *fast* tools for these types of operation:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
> df[, as.list(summary(dt)), by = group]
   group Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
1:     A   59   59.75   61.0   61   62.25   63
2:     B   63   64.25   65.5   66   66.75   71
3:     C   66   67.25   68.0   68   68.00   71
4:     D   56   59.75   61.5   61   63.00   64
```

Comment: @maximusyoda, to get scientific notation, use a custom function instead of `summary` such as: `tapply(df$dt, df$group, function(x) format(summary(x), scientific = TRUE))`

Comment: How can you export this list into a data frame?

Comment: @JorgeParedes, do you mean the list of summary statistics? I use the `data.table` package for these kinds of operations usually. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 69):

**dplyr** package could be nice alternative to this problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(dt),
            sum = sum(dt))
```

To get 1st quadrant and 3rd quadrant

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(q1 = quantile(dt, 0.25),
            q3 = quantile(dt, 0.75))
```

Answer (score 45):

Using Hadley Wickham's purrr package this is quite simple. Use `split` to split the passed `data_frame` into groups, then use `map` to apply the `summary` function to each group.

```
library(purrr)

df %>% split(.$group) %>% map(summary)
```

Comment: df %>% group_by(group) %>% do(data.frame(summary(.))) should do something similar in dplyr

Comment: This seems to produce identical output as the `tapply` approach using base R.

Answer (score 22):

There's many different ways to go about this, but I'm partial to `describeBy` in the `psych` package:

```
describeBy(df$dt, df$group, mat = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 13):

take a look at the `plyr` package.  Specifically, `ddply`

```
ddply(df, .(group), summarise, mean=mean(dt), sum=sum(dt))
```

Answer (score 12):

after 5 long years I'm sure not much attention is going to be received for this answer, But still to make all options complete, here is the one with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , list(mean_gr = mean(dt), sum_gr = sum(dt)) , by = .(group)]
#   group mean_gr sum_gr
#1:     A      61    244
#2:     B      66    396
#3:     C      68    408
#4:     D      61    488
```

Answer (score 9):

The `psych` package has a great option for grouped summary stats:

```
library(psych)
    
describeBy(dt, group="grp")
```

produces lots of useful stats including mean, median, range, sd, se.

Answer (score 7):

While some of the other approaches work, this is pretty close to what you were doing and only uses base r. If you know the aggregate command this may be more intuitive.

```
with( df , aggregate( dt , by=list(group) , FUN=summary)  )
```

Comment: shout out to this one for using base R, returning a data.frame, and using the summary function so I don't need to write one.

Comment: Careful: it does not return a data.frame (each column in the resulting summary visualization is not a data.frame name). It's a nice, efficient, clever solution.

Answer (score 6):

Besides `describeBy`, the `doBy` package is an another option. It provides much of the functionality of SAS PROC SUMMARY. Details: 
http://www.statmethods.net/stats/descriptives.html

Comment: Another quick way to tabulate data (without descriptive stats) is to use `freq` function in the `descr` package. That is not strictly what you asked for, but may still be instructive. Details: http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/descr/functions/freq

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why the [popular `skimr` package](https://github.com/ropensci/skimr/) hasn’t been brought up. Their function `skim()` was [meant to replace the base R `summary()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/skimr/man/skim.html) and supports `dplyr` grouping:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(skimr)

starwars %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  skim()

#> ── Data Summary ────────────────────────
#>                            Values    
#> Name                       Piped data
#> Number of rows             87        
#> Number of columns          14        
#> _______________________              
#> Column type frequency:               
#>   character                7         
#>   list                     3         
#>   numeric                  3         
#> ________________________             
#> Group variables            gender    
#> 
#> ── Variable type: character ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>    skim_variable gender    n_missing complete_rate   min   max empty n_unique
#>  1 name          feminine          0         1         3    18     0       17
#>  2 name          masculine         0         1         3    21     0       66
#>  3 name          <NA>              0         1         8    14     0        4
#>  4 hair_color    feminine          0         1         4     6     0        6
#>  5 hair_color    masculine         5         0.924     4    13     0        9
#>  6 hair_color    <NA>              0         1         4     7     0        4
#> # [...]
#> 
#> ── Variable type: list ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>   skim_variable gender    n_missing complete_rate n_unique min_length max_length
#> 1 films         feminine          0             1        9          1          5
#> 2 films         masculine         0             1       24          1          7
#> 3 films         <NA>              0             1        3          1          2
#> 4 vehicles      feminine          0             1        3          0          1
#> 5 vehicles      masculine         0             1        9          0          2
#> 6 vehicles      <NA>              0             1        1          0          0
#> # [...]
#> 
#> ── Variable type: numeric ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>   skim_variable gender    n_missing complete_rate  mean     sd    p0   p25   p50
#> 1 height        feminine          1         0.941 165.   23.6     96 162.  166. 
#> 2 height        masculine         4         0.939 177.   37.6     66 171.  183  
#> 3 height        <NA>              1         0.75  181.    2.89   178 180.  183  
#> # [...]
```

Answer (score 4):

With more recent (>1.0) versions of `dplyr` you can do so with

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)  %>% 
  summarise(as_tibble(rbind(summary(Sepal.Length))))
```

This works because dplyr will unpack the result of `summarise` into columns if the argument evaluates into a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend gtsummary (written by Daniel D. Sjoberg et al). You can generate publication-ready or presentation-ready tables with the package. A gtsummary solution to the example given in the question would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

data <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 
          71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4,6,6,8)))
df <- data.frame(group=grp, dt=data)


tbl_summary(df, 
            by=group,
            type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
            statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})","{median} ({IQR})", "{min}- {max}"), ) %>% 
  add_stat_label(label = dt ~ c("Mean (SD)","Median (Inter Quant. Range)", "Min- Max"))
```

which then gives you the output below

| Characteristic | A, N = 4 | B, N = 6 | C, N = 6 | D, N = 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dt |  |  |  |  |
| Mean (SD) | 61.0 (1.8) | 66.0 (2.8) | 68.0 (1.7) | 61.0 (2.6) |
| Meian (IQR) | 61.0 (2.5) | 65.5 (2.5) | 68.0 (0.8) | 61.5 (3.2) |
| Min- Max | 59.0 - 63.0 | 63.0 - 71.0 | 66.0 - 71.0 | 56.0 - 64.0 |

You can also export the table as word document by doing the following:

```
Table1 <-  tbl_summary(df, 
                by=group,
                type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
                statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})","{median} ({IQR})", "{min}- {max}"), ) %>% 
      add_stat_label(label = dt ~ c("Mean (SD)","Median (Inter Quant. Range)", "Min- Max"))

tmp1 <- "~path/name.docx"

Table1 %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  flextable::save_as_docx(path=tmp1)
```

You can use it for regression outputs as well. See the package reference manual and the package webpage for further insights

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtsummary/index.html
https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First, it depends on your version of R. If you've passed 2.11, you can use aggreggate with multiple results functions(summary, by instance, or your own function). If not, you can use the answer made by Justin.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689049/summary-statistics-using-apply-family-for-different-factor-levels) may also work,

```
spl <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
list.of.summaries <- lapply(spl, function(x) data.frame(apply(x[,3:6], 2, summary)))
list.of.summaries
```

Answer (score 0):

`collapse` offers a very flexible function for summary statistics with `qsu`:

```r
library(collapse)
with(df, qsu(dt, g = group))

#    N  Mean      SD  Min  Max
# A  4    61  1.8257   59   63
# B  6    66  2.8284   63   71
# C  6    68  1.6733   66   71
# D  8    61  2.6186   56   64
```

---

It's also very fast:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tapply = tapply(df$dt, df$group, summary),
  dt = setDT(df)[, as.list(summary(dt)), by = group],
  collapse = qsu(df$dt, g = df$group),
  purrr = df %>% split(.$group) %>% purrr::map(summary)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
#    tapply  453.2  503.75  531.718  522.70  548.6  946.8   100
#        dt  998.8 1076.90 1288.057 1127.55 1205.9 9569.6   100
#  collapse   14.8   24.45   38.432   36.90   43.9  121.6   100
#     purrr 2553.6 2728.85 2847.378 2816.75 2940.8 3715.8   100
```