# Binning column and getting corresponding values from other column in R

Tags: r, hmisc

I have two columns of paired values in a data frame, I want to bin the data in one column using the [`cut2`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Hmisc/docs/cut2) function from the [`Hmisc` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) so that there are at least say 25 data points in each bin. I however need the corresponding values from the other column. Is there a convenient way for that using R? I have to bin the column B.

```
A           B
-10.834510  1.680173
11.012966  1.866603
-16.491415  1.868667
-14.485036  1.900002
2.629104  1.960929
-3.597291  2.005348
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by wanting the "corresponding values of the other column". The first part is easy to accomplish using the g  (# of groups) argument:

```
dfrm$Agrp <- cut2(dfrm$A, g=trunc(length(dfrm$A)/25) )
```

You can aggregate means or medians of B within Agrp's using `tapply` or `ave` or one of the Hmisc summary functions. There are several worked examples in one of today's questions: [How to get Summary statistics by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847054/how-to-get-summary-statistics-by-group) as well as many other examples of using those functions or `aggregate` or the pkg:plyr functions.

Given that the number of B values will not necessarily be constant across groups the only way I can think to deliver the individual values by A-grouped-value would be with `split`. I added an extra row to illustrate that a non-even split might need to return a list rather than a more "rectangular" object :

```
dat <- read.table(text="A           B
 -10.834510  1.680173
 11.012966  1.866603
 -16.491415  1.868667
 -14.485036  1.900002
 2.629104  1.960929
 -3.597291  2.005348\n 3.5943 3.796", header=TRUE)
 dat$Agrp <- cut2(dat$A, g=trunc(length(dat$A)/3) )
 split(dat$B, dat$Agrp)
 #-----    
$`[-16.49, 2.63)`
[1] 1.680173 1.868667 1.900002 2.005348

$`[  2.63,11.01]`
[1] 1.866603 1.960929 3.796000
```

If you want the vector of values on which the splits were done then that can be accomplished by using regex on  `levels(dat$Agrp)`.

Comment: I've no problem in binning the data (the first part). For the second part, as an example say if the first bin contains the first four values of column B, I need to get the four corresponding values of column A, preferably in a vector

Comment: Language can be somewhat imprecise. I was demonstrating binning the  A values. Just reverse A and B if you were thinking of binning on the B values. Maybe if you make reference to the concrete example above I will understand what sort of "correspondence" you are thinking about.