# Summary statistics using apply family for different factor levels

Tags: r, statistics, apply, summary, tapply

I am trying to find the summary statistics for different factor levels.

```
data.frame(apply(final_data[Company=="BPO",c(66:84)],2,summary))
```

Now I have different values for `company` - i can repeat the statement for different values.  I know it can be automated - using apply family (`ddply`,`tapply`,`sapply`), but I am not getting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split on company and then use your function:

```
spl = split(final_data, final_data$Company)
list.of.summaries = lapply(spl, function(x) data.frame(apply(x[,66:84], 2, summary)))
```

Comment: thanks. I got correlation to work. with following `by(final_data[,c(66:85)],Company,function(x) cor(x))`

Comment: Sure, or: list.of.cor = lapply(spl, function(x) cor(x[,66:84]))

Answer (score 2):

You may want to think about using the `by` or `tapply` functions. This will allow you to skip the explicit call to `split`. Here's an example, since you haven't provided data.

```
# some example data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(rep(1:5, each=10)), y1=rnorm(50), y2=rnorm(50))

# with `tapply`
a <- do.call(rbind, sapply(df[,2:3], function(i) tapply(i, df$x, summary)))
# with `by`
a <- do.call(rbind, sapply(df[,2:3], function(i) by(i, df$x, summary)))
```

Here's the output:

```
> a
         Min.  1st Qu.    Median    Mean 3rd Qu.   Max.
 [1,] -0.8356 -0.54620  0.256600  0.1322  0.5537 1.5950
 [2,] -2.2150 -0.03775  0.491900  0.2488  0.9132 1.5120
 [3,] -1.9890 -0.39760  0.009218 -0.1337  0.5694 0.9190
 [4,] -1.3770 -0.32140 -0.056560  0.1207  0.6693 1.3590
 [5,] -0.7075 -0.23120  0.126100  0.1341  0.6619 0.8811
 [6,] -1.1290 -0.55080  0.103000  0.1435  0.5268 1.9800
 [7,] -1.8050 -0.02243  0.171000  0.4512  1.2720 2.4020
 [8,] -1.2540 -0.67980 -0.221100 -0.2477  0.2372 0.6107
 [9,] -1.5240 -0.26190  0.300000  0.1274  0.5380 1.1780
[10,] -1.2770 -0.56560  0.042540  0.1123  1.0450 1.5870
```

You might also want to combine this with the variable and level names to know what's going on:

```
b <- expand.grid(level=levels(df$x),var=names(df[,2:3]))
cbind(a,b)
```

Here's the output of that:

```
> cbind(b,a)
   level var    Min.  1st Qu.    Median    Mean 3rd Qu.   Max.
1      1  y1 -0.8356 -0.54620  0.256600  0.1322  0.5537 1.5950
2      2  y1 -2.2150 -0.03775  0.491900  0.2488  0.9132 1.5120
3      3  y1 -1.9890 -0.39760  0.009218 -0.1337  0.5694 0.9190
4      4  y1 -1.3770 -0.32140 -0.056560  0.1207  0.6693 1.3590
5      5  y1 -0.7075 -0.23120  0.126100  0.1341  0.6619 0.8811
6      1  y2 -1.1290 -0.55080  0.103000  0.1435  0.5268 1.9800
7      2  y2 -1.8050 -0.02243  0.171000  0.4512  1.2720 2.4020
8      3  y2 -1.2540 -0.67980 -0.221100 -0.2477  0.2372 0.6107
9      4  y2 -1.5240 -0.26190  0.300000  0.1274  0.5380 1.1780
10     5  y2 -1.2770 -0.56560  0.042540  0.1123  1.0450 1.5870
```