# error in user defined function which generate statistics by group

Tags: r, function, arguments, subset

I'm trying to make function to return statistics by group like followings.
To make statistics by group, I used subset in this function code.
But errors occurred when argument 'y' is applied to 'subset'.
How can I solve this problem? I'll wait wisdom of yours.
It's sure that tapply can be used, but my intention is to make function.
Thank you.

```
sbyg<-function(dt,grp,y) {
# dt=data.frame, grp=group variable, y=value variable
ng<-length(unique(grp))
x<-as.vector(unique(grp))
statis<-matrix(nrow=ng,ncol=6)
for (i in 1:ng) {
  dta<-dt[grp==x[i],]
  attach(dta)
  statis[i,1]<-nrow(dta) # 건수
  statis[i,2]<-colSums(!is.na(dta))[1] # nonmiss건수
  statis[i,3]<-mean(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE) # 평균
  statis[i,4]<-median(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE) # 중위수
  statis[i,5]<-min(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE)
  statis[i,6]<-max(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE)
  detach(dta)
}
rownames(statis)<-x
colnames(statis)<-c("count","nonmiss","mean","median","min","max")
statis
}

sbyg(iris,Species,Sepal.Length)  # error occurs
```

Comment: You can use one of the group by functions to do this For example with `aggregate` or `data.table` or `ddplyr`

Comment: idem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847054/how-to-get-summary-statistics-by-group)

Answer (score 1):

Your call of the function should be this:

```
sbyg(iris,"Species","Sepal.Length")
```

unless iris is a `data.table` object (which is not by default).

edit: Modified function:

```
sbyg<-function(dt,grp,y) {
  # dt=iris ; grp="Species"; y="Sepal.Length"
  ng<-length(unique(dt[, grp]))
  x<-as.vector(unique(dt[, grp]))
  statis<-matrix(nrow=ng,ncol=6)
  for (i in 1:ng) { # i <- 1
    dta<-dt[dt[, grp]==x[i],]
    statis[i,1]<-nrow(dta) # 건수
    statis[i,2]<-colSums(!is.na(dta))[1] # nonmiss건수
    statis[i,3]<-mean(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE) # 평균
    statis[i,4]<-median(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE) # 중위수
    statis[i,5]<-min(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE)
    statis[i,6]<-max(dta[,y],na.rm=TRUE)
  }
  rownames(statis)<-x
  colnames(statis)<-c("count","nonmiss","mean","median","min","max")
  statis
}
```

But this is not an optimal function. The best way is to use `tapply`.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer, YCR
quotation mark(") almost solved my problem.
but, 'by group' doesn't work.
I wonder what's the problem.