Create a summary() table by date in R
This must be simple, but I can't find guidance how to accomplish it.  I've got a very simple (sample below), with a date variable and a temperature variable.  The output I want is a data frame by date (i.e., one row per date) with a column for each of the outputs of the summary function:
> summary(temp$coretemp)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  103.0   116.0   118.0   117.5   119.0   128.0 

Here's the input dataframe (much truncated):
temp <- structure(list(coretemp = c(128L, 128L, 128L, 119L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 118L, 118L, 120L, 120L, 118L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 118L, 120L, 
123L, 119L, 119L, 117L, 116L, 121L, 121L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
119L, 119L, 103L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 120L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 116L, 
115L, 115L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 107L, 114L, 114L, 113L, 118L, 118L
), date = structure(c(19875, 19875, 19875, 19875, 19875, 19875, 
19875, 19875, 19875, 19876, 19876, 19876, 19876, 19876, 19876, 
19876, 19876, 19876, 19876, 19876, 19877, 19877, 19877, 19877, 
19877, 19877, 19877, 19877, 19877, 19877, 19878, 19878, 19878, 
19878, 19878, 19878, 19878, 19878, 19878, 19878, 19879, 19879, 
19879, 19879, 19879, 19879, 19879, 19879, 19879, 19879), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")

It looks from my googling as though summarise_by_time used to do what I'm trying to do (see https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/timetk/html/summarise_by_time.html), but it does not appear to be available in modern dplyr and I can't find what's replaced it.
I've also tried describe_by thus:
describe.by(temp, group = temp$date)

but it returns summary of both the date column AND the coretemp column which is unhelpful.

I am voting to close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847054/how-to-get-summary-statistics-by-group Also array2DF(with(X, tapply(coretemp, date, summary))).

That thread has a variety of solutions of more or less utility, but it does appear that workable answers are there ... I'm OK with closing.  Of course this thread was NOT one of the ones that came up in my search LOL

Turned out to be easier than I thought.  Here's my dplyr solution:
TempSum <- temp %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(low = min(coretemp),
            hi = max(coretemp),
            mean = mean(coretemp),
            median = median(coretemp),
            IQR = IQR(coretemp))

Which resulted in the following output:
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  date       low    hi  mean median   IQR
  <chr>    <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 6/1/2024   116   128  121.    118 12   
2 6/2/2024   113   123  118.    119  4.5 
3 6/3/2024   116   121  118.    118  1   
4 6/4/2024   103   120  116.    116  2.75
5 6/5/2024   107   118  115     116  3   


another solution:
df <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(temp$coretemp, temp$date, summary))) 
new_df = t(df)  


similar data.frame(do.call(rbind, tapply(temp$coretemp, temp$date, summary)), check.names = FALSE)
